# Application crashes with - dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UITraitCollection

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UITraitCollection
```

The only place in the code I have reference to the UITraitCollection is:

```
func loadImages(imageName: NSString) {
    var image: UIImage
    images = NSMutableArray(capacity: 7)
    for i in 0..7 {
        image = UIImage(named:"\(imageName)\(i).png", inBundle:nil, compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil)

        if (image != nil) {
            images.addObject(image)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using ios8 as your build target?

Comment: I am not using ios8 as a target, I am trying to get this working for ios6.1 target. I just tested it again with simulator and it works fine. But when I run it on the device (iPhone 5, 7.11 os) it crashes

Comment: [See this Answer for crash in trait collection ios7][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728394/854258

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITraitCollection is only part of the Foundation framework starting with ios8. What this error is saying is that the OS for your phone (7.1.1) doesn't have UITraitCollection in its library, which is true, since this class is only part of the ios8 Foundation.framework library. In order to cut down on app size, the Apple libraries are all dynamically loaded at runtime so they don't have to be packaged with your app, so your app only has access to the ios7 Foundation.framework on that particular iPhone. If you upgrade your iPhone to ios8, it should work.

Comment: Is there are a different way to load an UIImage then, so that it would be compatible with older os?

Comment: Yeah, I think you can just take out the trait collection part of the code, `image = UIImage(named:"\(imageName)\(i).png")`. I haven't started exploring swift yet.

Answer (score 0):

rvijay007's explanation is correct, but the solution is partial (you don't have to upgrade your device to iOS 8! It supports backwards compatibility). Here's the correct answer:

Try re-adding Foundation.framework:

1. Go to your project's target
2. Choose "General" tab
3. Under "Linked Frameworks an Libraries" look for Foundation.framework, select it and press the minus ('-') sign at the buttom to remove this framework.
4. Now press the plus sign ('+') and search for Foundation.framework - re-add it, and it's supposed to fix your crash.

Hope it works - it did for me.