# Accessing UIViewcontroller.traitCollection compiles but crashes my app

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xcode6

My storyboard is build in xcode6 and is using the new constraint based layouts. My app runs in two configurations, wRegular hRegular and wCompact hAny. Any time I try to access the traitCollection in code I get the following error:

```
[MYUIControllerName traitCollection]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.
```

I have also tried implementing the following function, but it never gets called.

```
-(void)willTransitionToTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)newCollection withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
```

Comment: What are you running on?  (Device/simulator, iOS version...?)

Comment: The app is crashing on both my devices, iPad Air iOS7 and an iPhone 5s iOS7.

Comment: I believe the traits feature requires iOS 8.

Comment: You are right, I just looked around a bit more and found [this](http://carpeaqua.com/2014/06/14/thinking-in-terms-of-ios-8-size-classes/) article stating traitCollections only work on iOS8. Is there a way to mark your comment as the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's exactly right that size classes don't work < iOS 8. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/DeployingSizeClassesonEarlieriOSVersions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH13-SW1

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue.
The answer is use trait collection only in viewWillAppear and willTransitionToTraitCollection. Theses are the only method when you can be sure they are set and correctly set. In iOS8 it can not crash but your trait collection will be unspecified.