# iOS app with framework crashed on device, dyld: Symbol not found, Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, rx-swift, carthage

I have started new empty project in Swift 3.0 and try use `RxAlamofire`. I use `Carthage` for dependecies library ([tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/getting-started-with-carthage-to-manage-dependencies-in-swift-and-ios.html)) but I got framework crash and message:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __TMp7RxSwift18ReactiveCompatible
  Referenced from: /Users/michu/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7249C3ED-2CBC-41E4-A66D-BBC010CD70CD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B625B9D2-687C-4703-A6BF-C9E5F8861F44/recipemaster.app/Frameworks/RxAlamofire.framework/RxAlamofire
  Expected in: /Users/michu/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7249C3ED-2CBC-41E4-A66D-BBC010CD70CD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B625B9D2-687C-4703-A6BF-C9E5F8861F44/recipemaster.app/Frameworks/RxSwift.framework/RxSwift
 in /Users/michu/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7249C3ED-2CBC-41E4-A66D-BBC010CD70CD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B625B9D2-687C-4703-A6BF-C9E5F8861F44/recipemaster.app/Frameworks/RxAlamofire.framework/RxAlamofire
```

I don't know where might be a problem. Below General configuration

[image: general]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

taken from Carthage´s github

"If you're building for iOS, tvOS, or watchOS

1. Create a Cartfile that lists the frameworks you’d like to use in your project.
2. Run carthage update. This will fetch dependencies into a Carthage/Checkouts folder, then build each one.
3. On your application targets’ “General” settings tab, in the “Linked Frameworks and Libraries” section, drag and drop each framework you want to use from the Carthage/Build folder on disk.
4. On your application targets’ “Build Phases” settings tab, click the “+” icon and choose “New Run Script Phase”. Create a Run Script in which you specify your shell (ex: bin/sh), add the following contents to the script area below the shell:

   /usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks

and add the paths to the frameworks you want to use under “Input Files”, e.g.:

```
$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Box.framework
$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Result.framework
$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/ReactiveCocoa.framework
```

"

https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#if-youre-building-for-ios-tvos-or-watchos

Answer (score 0):

In my case working this :

1. Under "Linked Frameworks an Libraries" look for Foundation.framework, select it and press the minus ('-') sign at the button to remove this framework.
2. Now press the plus sign ('+') and search for Foundation.framework - re-add it, and it's supposed to fix your crash.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24368642/3901620

Comment: I don't have Foundation.framework under "Linked Frameworks an Libraries" But I just added and stilll the same...

Comment: then you need to add only