# Carthage Symbol not found when try Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire, carthage, alamofireimage

I am trying `Carthage` and I thought [raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/416-carthage-tutorial-getting-started) blog post is awesome to start. So I download the starter project, then set my `Carthage` settings, I dragged then dropped my `Alamofire.framework` & `AlamofireImage.framework` files to `Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content`. Then I add `run script` which is `/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks`, after that add input files as paths of the frameworks.

```
$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Alamofire.framework
$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/AlamofireImage.framework
```

And when I clean & run the project it stuct at

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _$s9Alamofire14SessionManagerCN
  Referenced from: /Users/fiyuu/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E42E9DED-5A99-44C8-A0EB-0FF765CB8FB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C102F9B5-402A-40F3-A450-B0D420A7722D/DuckDuckDefine.app/Frameworks/AlamofireImage.framework/AlamofireImage
  Expected in: /Users/fiyuu/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E42E9DED-5A99-44C8-A0EB-0FF765CB8FB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C102F9B5-402A-40F3-A450-B0D420A7722D/DuckDuckDefine.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
 in /Users/fiyuu/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E42E9DED-5A99-44C8-A0EB-0FF765CB8FB3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C102F9B5-402A-40F3-A450-B0D420A7722D/DuckDuckDefine.app/Frameworks/AlamofireImage.framework/AlamofireImage
```

Even I do not import and no-use `Alamofire`, it fails.

Then I try to solve this problem via other questions and in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24368642), it thought `Foundation.framework` must be added. So I tried it but there's no effect for the problem.

```
Xcode Version: Version 11.0 (11A420a)
```

So do you have any idea about the problem? Maybe I must add extra flag for build or something? And `Referenced from` library and `Expected in` seems the installation is not successful, is it possible to solve with re-building the frameworks?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my question with using `Alamofire` dependency without specify any target or version in `Cartfile`.

The error occurs from the `github "Alamofire/Alamofire" "5.0.0-rc.2"` line, in new `Alamofire` you can use it with `AF.request(...)` and this version not successfully generate framework for me.

So I change the line with just `github "Alamofire/Alamofire"` then updated my `Carthage`, so it work well for me.